# Core Data crash on fetch with predicate "id in array"

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

I create a fetch to get some friends (the 'friend_id' is the property of Friend entity):

```
NSPredicate* perdicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"friend_id IN %@", aryFriendIds];
```

Sometimes it will crash -- happened once till now.

```
Thread 11:

0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x313bc848 __kill + 8

1   Messenger                     0x00026fcc -[CrashInfoReporter fatalSignal:Handler_Impl:With:] (CrashInfoReporter.m:575)

2   Messenger                     0x000250aa fatal_sig_handler (CrashInfoReporter.m:401)

3   libsystem_c.dylib             0x33ac47e6 _sigtramp + 42

4   CoreFoundation                0x3714fbe8 CFEqual + 100

5   CoreFoundation                0x3715b01e -[__NSCFString isEqual:] + 210

6   CoreFoundation                0x37165318 -[NSArray containsObject:] + 164

7   Foundation                    0x37aba56a -[NSInPredicateOperator performPrimitiveOperationUsingObject:andObject:] + 358

8   CoreData                      0x369e1b36 -[NSMemoryStoreInPredicateOperator performPrimitiveOperationUsingObject:andObject:] + 942

9   Foundation                    0x37a1a57e -[NSPredicateOperator performOperationUsingObject:andObject:] + 94

10  Foundation                    0x37a19be6 -[NSComparisonPredicate evaluateWithObject:substitutionVariables:] + 246

11  Foundation                    0x37a197bc -[NSPredicate evaluateWithObject:] + 16

12  CoreData                      0x36959284 -[NSManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:error:] + 2232
```

I can not figure out the problem because I can not reproduce it, but the crash line is 4   `CoreFoundation                0x3714fbe8 CFEqual + 100`, I guess the problem may be string comparing.

Thanks for any tips.

---

I've tried to add some `NSNumber or NSArray object` into `aryFriendIds` to let the CFEqual compare, but it works well.

Comment: You're trying to check if the string "id" is in the array?

Comment: @Wain of course not, the 'id' is the property of the Entity.

Comment: @JasonLee I think sometimes there's invalid data in array that you are providing. Try printing the array out so that you'll see when the format of the data is invalid

Comment: @art-divin Yes, I guess so too. So I've tried add some NSNumber or NSArray type into the aryFriendIds array, but it didn't crash. So what do you think of the invalid data format?

Comment: @JasonLee maybe some string is NULL in the original data?

Comment: @art-divin you mean NSNull, not nil, right? nil can not be inserted into an array.

Comment: @JasonLee yes, indeed I meant [NSNull null] by "NULL".
You can also try to deep-copy array before using it in fetch request

Comment: @art-divin I tried to insert [NSNull null] into the array, but it still ran well..........faint

Comment: @JasonLee maybe it was the data in the database itself? Try cleaning database maybe once the invalid value was written somehow